# Anacondaで仮想環境をcreateできません

Tags: python, anaconda

Anacondaでenvironmentからcreateボタンを押しても、右下のゲージが稼働中？のままでいつまでたっても仮想環境が出来上がりません。どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: OSは何でしょうか？Anacondaのバージョンは何でしょうか？ディスクやメモリには十分な空きがありますでしょうか？

Comment: OSはWindowsで、Anaconda Navigator 2.5.0です。ディスクは300GB以上あります

Comment: 最近はAnacondaNavigatorはあまり使っていないのですが、動作が重いアプリとは思います。確認ですが仮想環境作成以外の機能は通常通り使えていますか？（Anacondaが壊れていないかの確認です） またメモリをいっぱいいっぱい使っていたりはしませんか？ Windowsの場合OS再起動で治る場合もあるかと思います。

Comment: こちらの記事などを参考に、GUIで出来ないならCUIでやってみてはどうでしょう？ [【Anaconda】仮想環境の作り方と使い方についてわかりやすく解説](https://pyming.info/2022/11/20/anaconda_howtouse/)